# Admob displaying advertisement in my application in my device in android will disable my account?

Tags: android, google-play, admob

I have created and application and installed it in my own mobile also. It contains ads from admob. It shows advertisements when I use it. So will it disable my account from admob. I have not clicked on any ads they are simply displaying.

Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have not clicked on any ads they are simply displaying.

**No,** it will not disable your account if you are using the app genuinely and take care not to click on the ad intentionally with an intent of generating more revenue.

Better **keep your device added as a test device in your code when you create the ad request** so that even accidental clicks are not considered. That way you are safe as admob will always render test ads to this device.

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
    .addTestDevice("AC98C820A50B4AD8A2106EDE96FB87D4")  // An example device ID
    .build();
```

[Official Documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting) of how to add the test device.

Answer (score 1):

You only really risk disabling your account if the ads are clicked on. They have a system in place to test your app with dummy ad units, so you can make sure it actually works to click on them.

Comment: How can I know whether they tracked me? Actually i don't remember whether i clicked on ads or not...